# Linux/ Open directory as a file

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems, gnu

I've been reading Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie - The C Programming Language and chapter 8.6 is about directory listing under UNIX OS. They say that everything and even directory is a file. This means that I should be able to open directory as a file? I've tried it using stdio functions and it didn't work. Now, I'm trying it with UNIX system functions. Of course, I'm not using UNIX, I'm using Ubuntu linux. Here is my code:

```
#include <syscall.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argn, char* argv[]) {
    int fd;
    if (argn!=1) fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY,0);
    else fd=open(".",O_RDONLY,0);
    if (fd==-1) return -1;

    char buf[1024];
    int n;
    while ((n=read(fd,buf,1024))>0)
        write(1,buf,n);

    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

This writes nothing even when argn is 1 (no parameters) and I'm trying to read current directory. 
Any ideas/explanations? :)

Comment: No, look @ [`readdir`, `readdir_r` - read directory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/readdir.html) instead.

Comment: Better use `argc` instead of `argn` - it is normally used and leads to less confusion.

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie do indeed make the assertion that everything is a file. However, the book also states a bit later that `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` are designed to open, read, and close a `Dirent` structure, which is basically a portable description of a directory "file". File systems, however, differ between unix variants, which might explain why the system insists on using those special methods for directories.

Comment: Yes, I saw that they have implemented the Dirent structure, but they did it this way so that was confusing. Thanks for explanation about file systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files are also called `regular files` to distinguish them from `special files`.

Directory or not a `regular file`. The most common `special file` is the directory. The layout of a directory file is defined by the filesystem used.

So use [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) to open diretory.

Comment: Thanks! This is and previous answer and comment from @Achim explained it all about filesystem dependency, special files and errors that could occur. :)

Answer (score 4):

Nachiket's answer is correct (as indeed is sujin) but they don't clear up the mystery as to why `open` works and not `read`. Out of curiosity I made some changes to the given code to find out exactly what was going on.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd = -1;
    if (argc!=1) fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY,0);
    else fd=open(".",O_RDONLY,0);
    if (fd < 0){
      perror("file open");
      printf("error on open = %d", errno);
      return -1;
    }
    printf("file descriptor is %d\n", fd);

    char buf[1024];
    int n;
    if ((n=read(fd,buf,1024))>0){
        write(1,buf,n);
    }
    else {
      printf("n = %d\n", n);
      if (n < 0) {
        printf("read failure %d\n", errno);
        perror("cannot read");
      }
    }
    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The result of compiling and running this:

```
file descriptor is 3
n = -1
read failure 21
cannot read: Is a directory
```

That settles it, though I'd have expected `open` to fail, since the correct system function for opening directories is `opendir()`.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I saw that fd is 3, but I did not check the return form read. :)

Comment: Using `open()` on directories can occasionally be useful for use with calls that take a file descriptor, for example to use with `fchmod()`, `fchdir()`, or `fdopendir()`.  Though, the fd for the open directory can also be pulled out of a `DIR *` using `dirfd()`.

Comment: Best answer here, basically linux does not handle directories the same way as unix.

Answer (score 2):

Though everything in unix is a file (directory also) but still filetype is concept is present in unix and applicable to all files.
there are file types like regular file,directory etc and certain operations and functions are allowed/present for every file type.

In your case readdir is applicable for reading contents of directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the files in a directory you have to use the [`opendir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and [`readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) functions.

Answer (score 1):

K&R were correct for the original UNIX. I remember doing it back when UNIX file systems had a 14 character length limit for filenames.   The opendir(), readdir(), ... stuff happened about the time that longer file names became common (around 1990?)