# read directories withoud readdir

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls

I'm working on POSIX linux to learn. I'm using C Programming Languages.

I want to read a folder, but instead of using readdir or opendir, I want to use pure open and read, I want to extract subfolders or files in this folder as names as string.

Is this possible with open() and read() as open and read (without using dirent.h)?

Comment: This question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405048/linux-open-directory-as-a-file is there something you felt wasn't answered here?

Comment: On Linux you can play around with [`getdents64(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html), but as the man page repeatedly says, you really want `readdir()` instead

Comment: If you want to get the list of files in a specific directory, you should use [scandir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) or scandirat().  Otherwise, you're just reinventing a wheel (badly, because I bet you won't consider the possibility of files being renamed, deleted, or created during your scan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: no, it's not.

`open()` and `read()` operate on files, not directories.

`opendir()` and `readdir()` operate on directories, not files.